# Web API 2 returning text/plain responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api2

Really struggling with something I hope people here can help with.  I'm writing a RESTful API in Web API 2.  Whenever I send a request to this service, the response is consistently being sent with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`.  Obviously this is no good, my response needs to be `Content-Type` of `application/json`.  I've tried a few suggestions that I found from Google but I don't think I'm understanding the whole picture.

Is there something special I need to do in order to have my web service respond with `application/json` content?  Note that I want this to work globally across the whole app, so I'm not after a way to modify a given response and set its content type - I want this to be a default behaviour for the whole web service:  If a request contains an `Accept` header for `application/json` I want my web service to return that `Content-Type` instead of `text/plain`.

**Edit to clarify:**

My response contains an object called "responseData" that should be serialized into JSON and included in the body.  I'm currently putting together my response like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseData);
return response;
```

`responseData` is a POCO.  This get's correctly serialized as JSON and returned in the response - the only missing part is the Content-Type which is incorrectly set to "text/plain".  I could manually change this on every single response I compose, but I'm wanting to configure this on a global level.

Comment: Does the API in question return a `string` with JSON content you've built yourself?

Comment: Check this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation ,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574797.aspx,http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/22/asp-net-web-api-content-negotiation-and-accept-charset.aspx,

Comment: @Corey currently the response is created in this fashion: `HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseData);` and then I just return `response` in my action.  The contents of responseData are being serialised into JSON nicely, but the actual content-type header is still set to text/plain :(

Comment: @malkam that post seems to be dealing with Charsets, I'm interested in Content-Types

Comment: The link @malkam posted does point in the general direction of the answer, you just have to poke around in the library a bit more to see what the options are.\

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, assuming that your `responseData` is a string, the `Content-type` header will be `text/plain` when you create the `HttpResponseMessage`.  Doesn't matter what the contents of the string are, since no attempt is made to determine this.

The solution is to create the appropriate Content object for your message, initialized with the media type you're returning:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
                responseData,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            )
    };
```

There are other methods that amount to returning a particular object type and letting the API libraries serialize to JSON or XML for you as required.  I prefer to let the framework do the work for me where possible, but this is how you'd achieve it with a string you've created yourself.

---

For a strict JSON-only result, remove the XML formatter from the WebAPI configuration and return your POCO.

In `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`, add the following to the `WebApiConfig.Register` method:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

And for your API:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public bool result;
    public string reason;
}

public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public MyObject GetData()
    {
        MyObject result = new MyObject { result = "true", reason = "Testing POCO return" };
        return result;
    }
}
```

I ran this up and requested `/api/Test` from Chrome, which doesn't even mention `application/json` in the `Accept` header.  Here are the response headers up until it hits `Content-Type`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

And the body:

```
{"result":true,"reason":"Testing POCO return"}
```

Since I disabled XML it defaulted to JSON.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'm trying to find a global way to set this up, rather than having to explicitely define the Content Type for every response I create.  My wording was a bit unclear perhaps - I've edited my OP to hopefully clarify a couple of points.

Comment: Have you tried just returning the object itself?  `HttpResponseMessage` is fine when you want more control over individual returns, but you can return a POCO and let the libraries take care of serialization for you - JSON or XML, depending on the `Accept` header in the request.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that I'll still have a need to return 404s or 500s etc if something goes wrong - is that still possible using the described approach?

Comment: Yes, by throwing an [`HttpResponseException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{

JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
var jsonFormatter = new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings);
jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonFormatter);

}
```

Comment: This is assuming somebody has built a JsonNetFormatter of some sort, and doesn't work without that understanding or more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source of the issue described is that there may be an authorization redirect in play as was the case for us when one of the engineers thought to re-use user authentication for an api.

This means incoming requests were being redirected to a login page which was the `text/html` response that couldn't be parsed by `ReadAsync<>`. A silly mistake to be sure, but not an easy one to spot.

The solution in that case was to remove the user authentication and implement HMAC based authentication for the api.